# Draw 4 cards where: 3 cards same suit and remaining card of different suit

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Four cards are drawn from a standard 52-card deck without replacement. Find the probability that exactly 3 cards are of the same suit and the remaining card is of a different suit.

What I did:
(4C1)(13C3)(3C1)(13C1) divided by (52C4)

But the final right answer is 0.375.
Can you please tell me how to solve it and why mine is wrong? 
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I am actually dividing by (52C4) and still getting the wrong answer.

Comment: Your expression is now correct.

Comment: I don't get 0,375 either

Comment: Why do you think $0.375$ is the correct answer?

Comment: $0.375$ (which is $3$ out of $8$) seems too high to me even if I didn't know how to solve this problem cuz remember there are $4$ suits so you could get $1$ from each suit and you could also easily get $2$ max from one suit.  If I had to guess I would say no more than maybe $20$% "winners" based on your criteria.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 ways to choose the suit we want three of. There are then 3 ways to choose the remaining suit (we have one of). Then there are ${13 \choose 3}$ ways to choose the three card from the first suit, and $13$ ways to choose the card from the final one.

We divide this by ${52 \choose 4}$ ways to pick four cards, so we have as our probability:

$$\frac{4 \times 3 \times {13 \choose 3} \times 13}{{52 \choose 4}} \approx 0.1648$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider that there are 13 cards per suit. Then, to fulfill the stated conditions, we need

Then $P$($3$ cards same suit and $1$ card other suit| $4$ suits) = $4$ * $\dfrac{\binom{13}{3}\binom{39}{1}}{\binom{52}{4}}$ = $4$ * $\dfrac{286*39}{270,725}$ = $0.1648$

@Henno, @David, and @calculus: You are correct, there are four ways (suits) for this occur.

Comment: This seems wrong.  What about the 4 possible suits available?

Comment: I aggree with David.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to draw the cards one by one.

Draw 3 cards of the same suit and 1 card of another suit:

$yyyx$

In total there are 4 ways.

And the same kind of drawings can be made with the other 3 suits. Thus we have in total   $4\cdot (1+3)=16$ ways.

The probability of drawing cards one way is $\frac{13}{52}\cdot \frac{12}{51}\cdot \frac{11}{50}\cdot \frac{39}{49}$

All together the probabilitiy is $16\cdot \frac{13}{52}\cdot \frac{12}{51}\cdot \frac{11}{50}\cdot \frac{39}{49}\approx 0.1648$